# Parent UIViewController doesn't change orientation after Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have one `UIViewController` (called B) which I want to present (force) it in Landscape orientation. All of the other `UIViewControllers` presented in Portrait mode. In my project settings, only portrait mode is selected. 
My problem is that when I came back from B to A. It stucks on Landscape mode.

Inside AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is CheckImageCameraViewController {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

In controller A;

```
let controllerB = ControllerB()
self.present(controllerB,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

In Controller B;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
func closeButtonTapped(){
self.dismiss()
}
```

**EDIT:** When It is on A, If I move phone to change orientation. It looks in portrait.

Answer (score 2):

Override `viewWillAppear()` in A, check the orientation and take appropriate action.

Comment: From UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
, what is returned in viewDidAppear?